# Simple query about time complexity for Python "in"

Tags: python, complexity-theory

I have a function strip_punctuation(text) which takes in a string of text and removes all punctuation in it using a punctuation list. I am not sure about the time complexity whether it is O(N)*N or O(N^2). I think that it works where it is O(N) for N text length, and then O(N) for length of punctuation. May someone 
clarify the time complexity for this code?

```
def strip_punctuation(text):
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    stripped = ""
    for i in text:
        if i not in punctuations:
            stripped = stripped + i

    return stripped
```

Comment: I do notice that string concatenation in iteration (`stripped = stripped + i`) is not recommended and is consider O(N^2) in some style guide.

Comment: O(n^2) is probably right.  Look at the `maketrans()` and `translate()` functions in the standard library (exact details depend on the Python version you're using), they can almost certainly do this job faster (if only because the loop over characters is written in C instead of Python).

Answer (score 1):

If N is `len(text)`, then this is O(N):

```
for i in text
```

If M is `len(punctuations)`, then this code is O(M^2):

```
if i not in punctuations:
    stripped = stripped + i
```

That is because the whole `stripped` (which has length >= M) has to be copied M times (`stripped + i` makes a copy of `stripped`).

So, if both `text` and `punctuations` were inputs, the complexity would be O(N) * O(M^2), but in this case, M is a constant, so the **complexity is O(N)**.

Note that if `punctuations` was very very big, the function would be very very slow, but its complexity would still be just O(N), which only means that it is N times slower when the input is N times bigger.